# Change default mouse cursor on OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, mouse, osx-mavericks, cursor

Is there any way to change the default mouse cursor on OSX Mavericks?

More precisely, I'd like to make it look like in windows, and even more precisely I want to move the 'point' where the mouse cursor actually 'clicks' - on windows it's on the very end of the arrow, even outside of it, and on mac it's a little inside the arrow.

I've done some research, and all the websites either tell me to get Mighty Mouse, which doesn't work on my system, and other's tell me how to change the size of my cursor.

Comment: Try this link out, it explains quite well I hope! https://discussions.apple.com/message/19549001#19549001 Hope I have helped out!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for: https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape/releases. It is an open-source application I made that allows the customization of cursors for Mac OS X 10.8-10.10. It can import old MightyMouse files or you can create your own "cape". Included on that page is a link to download a remastered version of Max Rudberg's Svanslös cursors.

You can change the hotspot on your capes to be on the very edge of the cursor.

Good luck!

Comment: This resolves a years-long quest for the perfect i-beam cursor. I am a heavy terminal user (dark background, full-screen on second display). And OSX's default i-beam pointer simply does not cut it. Thanks to your app, it took me 2 minutes to make a pointer which is visible both on white and dark backgrounds.

Comment: Also works with the Yosemite GM, for the last few minutes I've had it.

Comment: I wrote more instructions for those who don't know much about cursors but still wish they could change the beach ball. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/157608/6748

Comment: @PeterHost, care to share your i-beam cursor?

Comment: For those after a better i-beam cursor, you can download a tiff here.. https://github.com/egold/better-xcode-ibeam-cursor

Comment: How about MacOS High Sierra 10.13?

Comment: Seems does not  work https://github.com/alexzielenski/Mousecape/issues/85.